# When are homology groups free abelian groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was working through some old qualifying exam problems and I am struggling with this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Let $n$ be a non-negative integer. For which values of $k = 0, ..., n$ is it true that for every (finite) simplicial complex $X$ of dimension  $n$, $H_k(X)$ is a free abelian group? Justify your answer.

Comment: Look up homology of real projective space.

Answer (score 7):

The only such $k$ are $0$ and $n$. For $k=0$ this is because $H_0(K)\cong \mathbb Z^c$ where $c$ is the number of connected components. For $k=n$, this is because $H_n(K)=\ker \partial_n\subset C_n(K)$ since $C_{n+1}(K)=0$. $C_n(K)$ is free abelian, so any subgroup is as well.

To show no other values work you need to find, for each middle dimension, a simplicial complex of dimension $n$ with torsion in that particular middle dimension. You can take $\mathbb{RP}^2$ for $k=1, n=2$. Then $\Sigma^{k-2}\mathbb{RP}^2$ is a $k$-complex with torsion in degree $k-1$. To get any $1\leq k\leq n-1$, take a union with $\Delta^n$ to bump the dimension up.